How to create table that logs old and new value
Consider the table "Names":



ID
Name




1
Paul


2
Tom


3
John



I would like to have a table "archive" that archives the changes that have been entered through a form in the following way:



ID
Name_before
Name_after




...
...
...



I have tried to implement this with AfterUpdate using the following code:
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("archive")

rs.AddNew
rs!Name_before = Me.Name.OldValue
rs!Name_after = Me.Name.Value
rs.Update

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub

This is currently not working. Can anyone tell me where the error lies or show me an alternative approach?

please, explain "not working". Are you getting an error? (which one?) or does it not behave as expected? (explain how). Note that ID cannot be the PK in the archive table as you might have more than one entry per ID. You are missing a DateTime column telling the order in which the changes ocured. So PK: (ID , DateTime column)
